# How to resolve a list separated by some nested property on their children?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I have a `Teacher` type that looks like this:

```
  type Teacher {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    reservations: [Applicant],
    reservations_by_day: {
      monday: [Applicant]
      tuesday: [Applicant]
      wednesday: [Applicant]
      thursday: [Applicant]
    }
  }
```

this is the `Applicant` type:

```
  type Applicant {
    id: ID!
    code: String
    name: String
    option: Option!
  }
```

And this is the `Option` type:

```
  type Option {
    id: ID!
    teacher: String
    time: String
    day: String
    workshop: Workshop!
  }
```

Basically I want to resolve `reservations_by_day` depending on the day the applicant chose. How could I code my resolver to accomplish this? Taking into account that the `day` prop is nested inside other stuff:

```
{
  Applicant {
    Option {
      day
    }
  }
}
```

Teacher resolvers

```
  Teacher: {
    options: (obj) =>
      db.options.filter((option) => option.teacher_id === obj.id),
    reservations: (obj) =>
      db.applicants.filter((applicant) =>
        new RegExp(obj.id).test(applicant.option_id)
      ),
      reservations_by_day: {
        monday: () => [],
        tuesday: () => [],
        wednesday: () => [],
        thursday: () => [],
      }
  }
```

Comment: Please show us the existing code for your `Teacher` resolvers

Comment: I edited my answer. Basically I have nothing so far for the `reservations_by_day` because I don't even know where to begin

Comment: Thanks. You'd just use `db.applicatants.filter` again, no? Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm a bit confused though why your `Teacher` has an `options` resolver but no `options` field in the schema. Also why are the `Teacher.applicants` filtered by an `option_id`? And why are you using regex for that?